# sequelize.js can't find pg dependency when using webpack

Tags: node.js, postgresql, npm, sequelize.js, webpack

When requiring sequelize I get some warning about "Critical dependencies".
After running the app I get the following error: "Error: The dialect postgres is not supported. (Error: Please install 'pg' module manually)".

Both pg and pg-hstore are however installed.

I think the problem is with sequelize.js dynamically looking for postgres. I tried to use the webpack ContextReplacementPlugin, but I have no idea how.

I'm using the  React Starter Kit boilerplate. The code that causes the problem is nothing more than this:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
//get the database info
import { dbModelLocation} from '../config';
import { dbConnectionConfig } from '../config';

var sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConnectionConfig.name,
  dbConnectionConfig.user,
  dbConnectionConfig.pass,
  dbConnectionConfig.options);
```

The exact warnings I get from webpack are:

> WARNING in ./~/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js Critical dependencies:
>   636:60-73 the request of a dependency is an expression  @
>   ./~/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js 636:60-73
>
> WARNING in ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js
>   Critical dependencies: 15:15-71 the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mssql/connection-manager.js
>   15:15-71
>
> WARNING in ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js
>   Critical dependencies: 15:15-69 the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js
>   15:15-69
>
> WARNING in ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js
>   Critical dependencies: 16:41-92 the request of a dependency is an
>   expression 16:102-153 the request of a dependency is an expression  @
>   ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js 16:41-92
>   16:102-153
>
> WARNING in ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js
>   Critical dependencies: 19:15-71 the request of a dependency is an
>   expression  @ ./~/sequelize/lib/dialects/sqlite/connection-manager.js
>   19:15-71

Comment: Can you post the code that causes these errors?

Comment: Just doing "var Sequelize = require('sequelize');" will give all the webpack warnings. Actually opening a connection gives the postgres error.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I'm getting that error and we're in 2019 with the latest version of sequelize... :(

Answer (score 3):

If you're like me ran into the same issue when using Webpack with Sqlite3 or MySQL, you'll need to use `externals` and define the dependencies:

```js
var config = {
  externals: ['pg', 'sqlite3', 'tedious', 'pg-hstore'],
};
```

Further information can be found in the following:

- Can't resolve [pg-hstore](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7509#issuecomment-361032176)
- Webpack [externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for answer on old questions, but I got the same error when I tried to use sequelize migrations. May be it will help someone.

You have to install 'pg' package globally and it will be work:

```
npm install -g pg
```

Answer (score -1):

[According to the Webpack author](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4879) the solution is to ignore `node_modules` while bundling.